# Is achartengine ready for realtime graphing?

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm trying to graph some real-time data, "realtime" here means < 10msec data, ideally as low as possible. I've been able to get Android to fetch and process data this fast but ACE just looks like it's not been designed for real-time use in mind. First symptoms are that garbage collector kicks in like there's no tomorrow and totally kills the app. I'm visualizing data on a "sliding window" fashion so it's not like I'm expecting ACE to plot in real time hundreds of thousandths of points.
I've taken a look at it and the onDraw for XYChart certainly allocates very heavily in cases where it looks like it's convenient and probably makes the code much more readable but not really required.
This might even be worse than it used to be so it might not have been noticed yet. I saw bugfix for issue #225 solved a concurrency problem changing:

`return mXY.subMap(start, stop);`

for:

`return new TreeMap<Double, Double>(mXY.subMap(start, stop));`

This creates huge allocations (still backed by the original subMap though) when it would probably be better to queue updates while onDraw is going on and process them later on atomic updates or something on that line to avoid concurrency issues.

The **real pity** here is that **ACE is certainly fast enough for what I need**. It can do what I need on my HW perfectly but since it allocates so heavily on repaint Android goes crazy with GC. It soon starts allocating while GC is running so it has to wait and my app starts looking like a stop-motion movie.

The real question though is: Is it reasonable to expect to be able to repaint 4 or 6 linecharts (tablet app) on realtime (sub 200ms refresh rate) with ACE or is it simply not prepared for that kind of abuse?
If the answer is no. Any other options there you'd recommend?

**EDIT 20130109:**
Revision 471 improves things quite a bit for small data sets. 2.000 points / 4 charts / 100 msec refresh rate is doable and smooth. Logs still see "GC_CONCURRENT freed" like crazy (around 10/sec) but no "WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked" which are the showstoppers that make your app stop-motion like.
At 3.000 points / 1 chart / 100 msec it's clearly **not** smooth. We get again the avalanche of "WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked" on logcat and the stuttering app. Again it looks like we do not have a speed problem, only a memory management problem.

*It may look like I might be asking ACE to do magic but I hit this wall after refactoring all my code to retrieve and store telemetry data at 1KHz. Once I finally saw my app retrieve and store all of that realtime without triggering GC at all I pulled my hair with ACE when trying to graph :)*

Comment: could you please share the link to your source code or any tutorial specific to drawing ECG in android app. I am trying to achieve the same, but I am not able to understand how to plot the X axis; what I get after parsing the ECG data from the ECG device is an array of numbers : 0.74, 0.732,.. etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a big effort on optimizing everything else on my app I still can't make it plot in what I understand for "realtime".
The library is great, and very fast but the way in which every onDraw allocates memory inevitably triggers an avalanche of garbage collection which collides with its own allocation and thus android freezes your app momentarily causing stutter which is totally incompatible with "realtime" graphing. The "stutter" here can range from 50-250ms (yes milliseconds) but that's enough to kill a realtime app.

AChartengine will allow you to create "dynamic" graphs just as long as you don't require them to be "realtime" (10 frames/sec, (<100ms refresh rate) or what you'd call "smooth").

If someone needs more information on the core problem here, or why I'm saying that the library is fast enough but memory allocation patterns end up causing performance problems take a look at [Google I/O 2009 - Writing Real-Time Games for Android](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4Bk5rmIpic)

Answer (score 2):

First of all thanks for the great question and for the point you raised. You were definitely right about the huge memory allocation that was done under the `onDraw()` method. I fixed that and checked in the code in SVN. I have also added a synchronized block inside the `onDraw()` method such as it will hopefully not throw `ConcurrentModificationException` when adding new data to the dataset during repaints.

Please checkout the code from SVN and do an ant dist in order to build new AChartEngine jar file and embed it in your application. Please see instructions [here](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/checkout).

To answer your question: AChartEngine is definitely ready for dynamic charting. The issue you reported was a show-stopper, but it should be fixed now. I have written dynamic charting using it. However, you need to make sure you don't add 100000s of data values to the datasets. Old data can be removed from the datasets in order to gain performance.

It is definitely reasonable to paint the 5 or so line charts if they have up to a few 1000s points.

Comment: I'll check that but I did revert that specific issue and still found GC was a problem. I delved deeper into the code with Eclipses allocation tracker and saw plenty of other problematic areas regarding allocation on onDraw. I can rig a test with the official demo so we can look at the same problem if you're willing to look into it but it'll take some refactoring around object factories / pools to make Ace work real time on Android. Are you testing this in HoneyComb? GC changed completely to a concurrent GC algorithm so it might not be an issue on previous versions.

Comment: I did a big refactoring on the code and checked in stuff in SVN. The places where data is copied and duplicated is a lot reduced. Can you please profile it again and let me know if things are improved now?

Comment: Do you need all the 10000 points * 4 charts to be displayed on the screen? Is it possible that you remove some of the data when no longer on screen?

Comment: Certainly. Bad news is that those numbers where just the first stress test i did. I've now looked just how high it could go smoothly and it looks like it's almost my initial test. It gets stuttering at 3.000 points / 1 single chart / 100 msec refresh rate. Just edited results. The refactoring was an optimization focused really on speed not memory, speed is good, memory not so when we need real time refresh times.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after some time looking for another graphing library I found nothing good enough :)
That made me look into ACE again and I ended up doing a small patch which makes it "usable" for me although far from ideal.

On XYSeries.java I added a new method:

```
/**
* Removes the first value from the series.
* Useful for sliding, realtime graphs where a standard remove takes up too much time.
* It assumes data is sorted on the key value (X component).
*/
public synchronized void removeFirst() {
  mXY.removeByIndex(0);
  mMinX = mXY.getXByIndex(0);
}
```

I found that on top of the memory issues there where some real speed issues at high speed framerates too. I was spending around 90% of the time on the remove function as I removed points which scrolled out of view. The reason is that when you remove a min|max point ACE calls InitRange which iterates over every point to recalculate those min/max points it uses internally. As I'm processing 1000 telemetry frames per sec and a have a small viewport (forced by ACE memory allocation strategies) I hit min/max points very often on the remove function.
I created a new method used to remove the first point of a series which will normally be called as soon as you add a point which makes that one scroll out of your viewport. If your points are sorted on key value (classic dateTime series) then we can adjust mMinX so the viewport still looks nice and do that very fast.
We can't update minY or maxY fast with the current ACE implementation (not that I looked into it though), but if you set up an appropriate initial range it may not be required. In fact I manually adjust the range from time to time using extra information I have because I know what I'm plotting and what the normal ranges are at different points in time.

So, this might be good enough for someone else but I insist that a memory allocation refactoring is still required on ACE for any serious realtime graphing.